# Filter auto complete drop down search results

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp, cedet

I have setup cedet+auto complete and got the recommendation system to work. However whenever the drop down menu of recommendations is shown, I expect the results to be filtered as I enter characters.
This is the screenshot:
[image]

So as I type `pu` I expect the drop down menu to contain results like `push_back`. How do I get that?

This is my .emacs file(relevant portions):

```
;;; yasnippet
;;; should be loaded before auto complete so that they can work together
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
(defun my:ac-c-header-init ()
  (require 'auto-complete-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'achead:include-directories '"/usr/include/c++/4.8"))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-header-init) 
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-header-init) 




(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(require 'auto-complete)
(ac-config-default)
(setq ac-auto-show-menu t)

(ac-flyspell-workaround)

;;cedet configuration
(semantic-mode 1)
(defun my:add-semantic-to-autocomplete ()
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-semantic))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my:add-semantic-to-autocomplete)

(global-ede-mode 1)
(global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode 1)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my:add-semantic-to-autocomplete)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my:add-semantic-to-autocomplete)


;; (defun my-semantic-hook ()
;;   (imenu-add-to-menubar "TAGS"))
;; (add-hook 'semantic-init-hooks 'my-semantic-hook)
;(require 'semantic/ia)
;(require 'semantic/bovine/gcc)
(defun my-c-mode-cedet-hook ()
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-gtags)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-semantic))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-cedet-hook)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-cedet-hook)


(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode t)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode t)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use `ac-isearch`. You can invoke it by `C-s` when completion tooltip is popuped.

1. popup completion tooltip(`M-x auto-complete` or auto start)
2. invoke `ac-isearch`(`C-s`)
3. filtering completions

Comment: Any idea how I should integrate ac-isearch with auto-complete?